# how use jquery script for new objects?

Tags: jquery

Good day.

On my page found script:

```
$('.crop_photo').on('click',function(){

$('#form_cropbox').ajaxForm(
{
url:        'update.php', 
success:    function(data) {
}
}).submit();
});
```

using other script I create a new objects(image and form) on page:

```
.....
$('#edit_photo').html(
'<img src="./Images/Temp/' + data + '" id="cropbox" width="600" />'+
'       <form action="update.php" method="post" id="form_cropbox" onsubmit="return checkCoords();">'+
'           <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />'+
'           <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />'+
'           <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />'+
'           <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />'+
'           <input type="hidden" id="f_count_v" name="f_count_v" value="'+ count + '" />'+
'           <input type="button" value="Сохранить область фотографии" class="btn btn-large btn-inverse crop_photo" />'+
'       </form>'
);
.....
```

But when i click on button with class "crop_photo" `$('.crop_photo').on('click',...` not work.

Where can be error?

Please tell me how right use first script ?

Comment: I see this question ten times a day, and the answer (is still) Event delegation.

Comment: @Zenith i dont know answer

Comment: The point is that '.crop_photo' didn't exist when you ran `$('.crop_photo').on('click',..`. That means it didn't get bound. Instead use pXL's code – they bind a click on to the surrounding element, then check if it's on the crop_photo button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use event delegation -

```
$('#edit_photo').on('click','.crop_photo',function(){
```

This is your code after change -

```
$('#edit_photo').on('click', '.crop_photo', function () {
    $('#form_cropbox').ajaxForm({
        url: 'update.php',
        success: function (data) {}
    }).submit();
});
```

- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1):

Since those are added dynamically [do Event Delegation](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events).

Use

```
$(document).on("eventname",'.crop_photo', function(event,ele){
 //Your code goes here
});
```